# Creating UI views for a large number of item types

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, architecture

I need to create UI views for types of products.
So for example a type of product may be hardware tools another type gardening tools another could be clothing garments etc.
I had in mind to create a layout file per type of product. This would simplify coding a lot. But that could lead to a large number of XML layout files and also creating a new layout file for each new type introduced.
I was wondering if there is any limits on the number of XML layout files we can have so that my approach could reach some limit or be considered a bad practice. Let's assume that the types is over 200.
Also is there some already establish pattern for this so that I could avoid creating a new XML file for each new type?

Comment: For each type of product when show on screen, Do you want the same arrangement lay-out or difference between ?

Comment: @TruongGiangDam:Different types will have different layouts